# Trigger an action when the value of an integer changes

Tags: ios, events, triggers, integer

I am building an app where the value of an integer can change randomly and I want to be able to hide or show a UIButton depending on the value of this integer.
However, I don't know how to trigger the status change when the value of the integer changes.

Is there any easy way to do it on iOS?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried anything? - And please show some code, preferably the part where the integer changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use observer pattern for this

```
[self.myVC addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"IntegerProperty" options:0 context:nil];
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if (object == self.myVC && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"IntegerProperty"]) {
        //do work
    }
}
```

Comment: Reactive Cocoa packages you the KVO APIs in a beautiful reactive interface. Anyone aiming for KVO should check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Your integer should be a property of a class and you should access it properly via the provided accessors (so use `self.xxx`). Then you can use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can use key value observer concepts, it works similar to notification centre...